# which is the best context to make an in app phone call

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I have the below code:

```
  Intent myintent = new Intent (ScreenOne.this, ScreenTwo.class);
  startActivity(myintent);
```

ScreenTwo consists of a list of phone numbers.
Both the screens extend BaseScreen.

What I need to do is click on a phone number and make a call from within my app.
I have the code right, only problem is the call screen is behind ScreenTwo.

I am guessing it is something to the with the context that I am passing in the Intent.

I have used

- ScreenOne.this,
- this,
- getBaseContext(),
- getApplicationContext(),
- getApplication and
- getParent(),

all to no avail.

Comment: The Class extends the Activity, why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no light shed on this, and all the contexts don't seem to work in bringing the screen to the top, I guess I'll have to find another workaround.

Answer (score 0):

`ScreenTwo` itself is supposed to be an `Activity` since it **extends Activity**. You should create some more new activities (and register them in `AndroidManifest.xml` too) and then call them as you are doing in your first approach.

Comment: When you make a phone call, Android initiates its own calling Activity (by default) to complete the process. You cant create your own customized call screen and bypass the default behaviour

Comment: it's not using the native dialer, it's within my app...I have already done the customised call screen, and I can access it from any screen but ScreenTwo :)